# eliminate the value of a variable in a service in android

Tags: android

my program is an activity to identify a user when that user is identified by pressing a button sends the string to another class (alarmChecker) that extends to a service. This service does is check every 30 seconds if the value of a database has changed, and if you notice changes launches.

Sending the String in the main class (MainActivity) I do it like this:

```
  / / Class MainActivity

  Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, alarmChecker.class);

  Bundle data = new Bundle ();
  data.putString ("user", user);
  intent.putExtras (data);
  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService (MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Then the class "alarmChecker" receives the parameter as follows:

```
 / / class alarmChecker

     @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
// Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 Bundle data = intent.getExtras();

 user = data.getString("user");

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "user: "+user, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and I want to do is if the user presses the Return button or exit the application and return to the main screen (MainActivity) and identifies with another different user, alarmChecker class take the new values​​, but the problem is that the grabs. Always have the values ​​you enter the first time.

How to solve it?

Thanks for answering and greeting.

Comment: What are you doing with the pendingIntent? if you're using an AlarmManager to launch your service on a regular basis and then change the pendingIntent after, the AlarmManager won't change, it was set up using the first one - changing it after you've started the AlarmManager won't change the Intent that gets delivered or the extras that go with it.

Answer (score 0):

For your immediate question, your service can be updated with new values if you implement [`onStartCommand()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) in your service - it gets called every time the service receives a start intent, regardless of whether or not it has already started..

Unrelated to the question, in the long term, you might consider rethinking  your design, as watching the database is a solved problem for you through the [`ContentObserver` API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html), which does this kind of event from database it sounds like you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, but don't work, I try again with this method onStartCommand(), but still doing the same. I edit in code what I said above.

Comment: In your example above, `Bundle data = intent.getExtras()` but on the next line you're pulling from `datos`.  Is that how your code really looks? or just a typo?

Comment: Sorry, Im spanish and I change the code from spanish to english but this is the same. Data in spanis is datos, sorry for that.

Comment: Nobody can answer my question?